# How merge two json data on Jekyll / Liquid

Tags: json, merge, jekyll, liquid

I have two .json data files (*en.json and en-br.json*) in folder *_data/i18n/*

I can access any data from these files using for example:

```
site.data.i18n.var1
```

What I like to do is to merge these two files by replacing the data from the first by the data in the second, provided they have the same index. OUT OF PLUGINS.

**en.json:**

```
{
"var1", "1111",
"var2", "2222",
"var3", "3333",
"var4": "4444"
}
```

**pt-br.json:**

```
{
"var1", "5555",
"var4": "6666"
}
```

The result that I hope would be:

```
myVariable.var1: 5555
myVariable.var2: 2222
myVariable.var3: 3333
myVariable.var4: 6666
```

I tried this:

```
{% assign txt = site.data.i18n.en %}
{% assign txt = site.data.i18n.pt-br %}
```

But the second overwrite the first clearing the missing fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot merge two hash with liquid.

One solution can be to use Jekyll configuration mechanism. This mechanism allows you to run jekyll with multiple configuration files ([documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#build-command-options)).

By running `jekyll serve --config _config.yml,_data/lang/en.yml,_data/lang/pt-br.yml`, you will have datas in `en.yml` merged with datas in `pt-br.yml` ''*the later file overriding datas in earlier*''.

**Note**: you have to format your files as yaml not json. Suggestion for `en.yml` :

```
lang:
  "var1": "1111"
  "var2": "2222"
  "var3": "3333"
  "var4": "4444"
```

Your variables are then available under `site.lang.variableName`.

**Note** : If you use github pages, you will have to generate locally and publish by hand.